# How to specify pyinstaller resource files correctlly?

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, executable

I want to make a runnable .py application by double click in Linux.
First, I tried a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2

img= cv2.imread('/home/andrei/WTZ/code/Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/test_image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('It works?', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It just opens an image, nothing special.
I installed pyinstaller and I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data="/home/andrei/WTZ/code/Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/test.jpg;/home/andrei/WTZ/code/Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/test.jpg" test.py
```

And I encounter the following error:

```
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: '/home/andrei/WTZ/code/Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/test.jpg;/home/andrei/WTZ/code/Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/test.jpg'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps try `--add-binary` instead?

Comment: Oh and DEST, if I understand correctly, is a path *relative* to the dist path.

Answer (score 0):

Ran this on my machine

```
pyinstaller --add-binary C:\Users\jezequiel\Desktop\diagram_new.png;.\images d.py
```

and the .PNG file was copied to a subdirectory named `images` in the folder containing the `d.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

So recommended approach is the first make a `main.spec` file -

```
pyi-makespec --windowed main.py
```

you should then get a `main.spec` file that you can call `pyinstaller` with - so you don't need to pass in all resource files via command line.

Then, in your `main.spec` file (which is actually python code), you should have something like

```
a = Analysis(
    ...
    )
```

Assuming your resources are in a `resources` directory in the root of your project, you can add them all to your build by adding a line that recursively walks through this directory and adds all files.  Your app should then be able to reference these files.

```
a = Analysis(
    ...,
    datas = [(os.path.join(dp, f), dp) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk('./resources') for f in filenames],
    )
```